# How to solve this 3D wooden puzzle which becomes an interlocking cross?

Tags: mechanical-puzzles, solvability

I got a 3D wooden puzzle in which you are supposed to rebuild. I took pictures of the 6 pieces (click images to enlarge):

[image: Piece#1]
[image: Piece#2]
[image: Piece#3]
[image: Piece#4]
[image: Piece#5]
[image: Piece#6]

I found this image on the Internet. I believe it's the solved version:

[image: Solution]

How do you solve it? Has anybody here done it?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

This is one of the most well-known wooden interlocking "Burr" puzzles, called The Chinese Cross. 
If you look at the two images below, you can see pieces that are the same shapes as yours, but with each one a different color. Using the colors as a guide, you can see how they fit together in the assembled version. 
The photos are from Rob Stegmann's page on interlocking puzzles, which has a great deal more information on this puzzle and many like it: [Rob's Puzzle Page](http://robspuzzlepage.com/interlocking.htm)

You might also be interested in the Burr Tools program, created by Andreas Röver. It can be used to analyze and solve a huge number of different types of burr puzzles, and can be found at the [BurrTools Sourceforge](http://burrtools.sourceforge.net/)

[image: Chinese Cross pieces]
[image: Chinese Cross assembled]

Here is a set of steps for assembly. The numbered pieces correspond to the colored pieces in the photo with the following mapping: 
4 - Red 
8 - Yellow 
13 - Green 
12 - Blue 
7 - Pink/Purple 
1 - Orange 
[image: Solution Steps]

 
You can also see a solution video here: [Solution Video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8rclzr24nS4)

Comment: really helpful using a color key! great work!

Comment: can you please actually include the steps of combining using the colours as a reference?

Comment: Thank you, but as d'alar said, steps would be nice (pictures will help)

Comment: Very nice answer