# Need help solving 3d wooden cross puzzle

Tags: mechanical-puzzles, three-dimensional

I'm trying to solve this puzzle and need some help with the solution:

[image: assembled version]

These are the pieces:

[image: puzzle pieces]

The size is: 60mm x 40mm x 10mm.

Any help appreciated.

**How do you solve this?**

Comment: Look around here: http://puzzling.stackexchange.com/a/2692/29343

Comment: It's a completely different puzzle

Comment: Oh God this is looking like the Gordian knot...

Comment: I have one similar to this, but it doesn't have the little notches inside

Comment: @YuryFedorov Is this a puzzle you possess? You took the photos? If so, could you share the measurements?

Comment: @Alenanno I edited my question. The size is: 60mm x 40mm x 10mm.

Comment: It's even harder actually when you can just look at the pieces and not actually hold them :P

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This looks like a variation of **Chen's 6 Board Burr #2**. An easier variation even, as the 5th piece in your picture should be "whole" like the 3rd one:

[image]

Solution (with pictures): http://www.puzzlewillbeplayed.com/6BoardBurr/Chen/2/solution.html

Comment: Right now this counts as a link only answer.

Answer (score 2):

Here is another solution, step by step

http://www.mywoodenpuzzles.com/#!/link_knot_six/solution/step_1_of_16

Answer (score 0):

Hm, looking at it, if we number the pieces
1 2 3
4 5 6

We know that the puzzle ends up with three pairs of pieces interlocked, and I'm fairly certain those pairs are 1&2, 3&5, and 4&6, because the notches in 1&2 and 4&6 match each other.

I could be wrong but I hope this helps?

Comment: To me, matching notches makes it more likely to not be paired together.

Comment: I agree.  I think the last two pieces to place should be 4 & 6 with 6 being the very last piece.  The first are 3 & 5.  Thus, you should place 1&2 inside 3&5 and then get 4&6 in.